# Grice's cooperative principless

Tags: historical-linguistics, cross-linguistic, origin-of-language

Based on Pragmatics Approach, there is one of the principle that involves in communication. It is cooperative principle. This principle consists of 4 maxims. There are maxim of quality (Truthful), maxim of quantity (Informative), maxim of relation (relevant), and maxim of manner (clear).
the question is: Can Grice's Maxims be applied on written texts
If yes, are there any studies; articles, dissertations so far?

Comment: [Grice's Maxims](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Grice.pdf)

Comment: I difficult to emphasise how MASSIVE Grice's impact has been, and how much work in a variety of disciplines treats it as foundational. In short, yes, there are no doubt thousands of pieces of work applying Gricean pragmatics to written text. I hate to be that guy, but try googling it.